# How allow others to update my site using Github?

Tags: web-development, github

Some sites are configured to update based on what is in a Github repository:

- Example 1: http://wpgear.org/ can be updated via https://github.com/ranukaherath/WordPress-Gear
- Example 2 : http://javascript.info can be updated via
  https://github.com/iliakan/javascript-tutorial-en

How I do something like above for my site?

Comment: You need to build an automation process in your web server to pull the data from GitHub.

Comment: @mootmoot Thanks. Please can you give a link / tutorial?

Comment: you can google "automate publish website github source". This topic can be pretty wide, as some may use complex testing and staging tools, to make sure nothing breaks during deployment.